# how to query number of present attendance percentage for each student & show percentage present count CodeIgniter framework

Tags: php, mysql

below is the code for crud_model.php
Required to add code to generate present percentage for each student into database when submit attendance

```
public function take_attendance()
    {
        $students = $this->input->post('student_id');
        $data['timestamp'] = strtotime($this->input->post('date'));
        $data['class_id'] = html_escape($this->input->post('class_id'));
        $data['section_id'] = html_escape($this->input->post('section_id'));
        $data['school_id'] = $this->school_id;
        $data['session_id'] = $this->active_session;
        $check_data = $this->db->get_where('daily_attendances', array('timestamp' => $data['timestamp'], 'class_id' => $data['class_id'], 'section_id' => $data['section_id'], 'session_id' => $data['session_id'], 'school_id' => $data['school_id']));
        if($check_data->num_rows() > 0){
            foreach($students as $key => $student):
                $data['status'] = $this->input->post('status-'.$student);
                $data['student_id'] = $student;
                $attendance_id = $this->input->post('attendance_id');
                $this->db->where('id', $attendance_id[$key]);
                $this->db->update('daily_attendances', $data);
            endforeach;
        }else{
            foreach($students as $student):
                $data['status'] = $this->input->post('status-'.$student);
                $data['student_id'] = $student;
                $this->db->insert('daily_attendances', $data);
            endforeach;
        }

        $this->settings_model->last_updated_attendance_data();

        $response = array(
            'status' => true,
            'notification' => get_phrase('attendance_updated_successfully')
        );

        return json_encode($response);
    }
```

[database fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZr5r.png)

Comment: Please assist on how do I add present percentage for each student?

Comment: you mean percentage of attandance? preset vs school days?

Comment: yes percentage of attendance.  present vs total number of attendance marked(usually every sundays for 1 year)

Comment: you need to have daily attendance table.

Comment: Yes i do have the daily attendance table. The database fields are shown on the above database fields link image. You can click the link to view the image and see the fields. I have created extra 2 blank fields(present and absent) to count number of number of presents and absent for each student.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the idea of what you want. You will have to analyze it and put it in your code.

```
if($check_data->num_rows() > 0){
    foreach($students as $key => $student):
        //add this in your code-----------
        $checker = array(
                    'school_id' => $this->school_id,
                    'status'    => 1         
                ); 
        $days_a_week = 5;
        $present_days = $this->getStudentDaysByID($checker);
        $data['present'] = ($present_days / $days_a_week) * 100;
        //--------------------------------
        $data['status'] = $this->input->post('status-'.$student);
        $data['student_id'] = $student;
        $attendance_id = $this->input->post('attendance_id');
        $this->db->where('id', $attendance_id[$key]);
        $this->db->update('daily_attendances', $data);
    endforeach;
}else{
 foreach($students as $student):
        $data['status'] = $this->input->post('status-'.$student);
        $data['student_id'] = $student;
        $this->db->insert('daily_attendances', $data);
        //add this in your code-----------
        $last_id = $this->db->insert_id();

        $checker = array(
                'school_id' => $this->school_id,
                'status'    => 1         
            ); 
        $days_a_week = 5;
        $present_days = $this->getStudentDaysByID($checker);
        $data2['present'] = ($present_days / $days_a_week) * 100;
        $attendance_id = $this->input->post('attendance_id');
        $this->db->where('id', $last_id);
        $this->db->update('daily_attendances', $data2);
        //--------------------------------
 endforeach;
 }

//put this outside your public function
function getStudentDaysByID($checker) {
    $StudentDaysByID = $this->db->get_where('daily_attendances', $checker);         
    return $StudentDaysByID->num_rows();     
}
```

Comment: `function getStudentDaysByID($student) {
        $checker = array(
            'school_id' => $this->school_id,
            'status'    => 1
        );
        $StudentDaysByID = $this->db->get_where('daily_attendances', $checker);
        return $StudentDaysByID->num_rows();
    }`

Comment: I have tried the above but it says 'Call to undefined function getStudentDaysByID()'. Is the above getStudentDaysByID function code correct to check present_days for each student. Thanks for assistance.

Comment: Try `$this->getStudentDaysByID($student)`

Comment: I doubt the function must call first. May i know where should i put the above code or replace. Any idea on how to set the algorithm to count number of present for each student

Comment: @zak put the function getStudentDaysByID outside the public function code.

Comment: Thanks Ajay.Some how the above works. By the way,when first time data goes in based on student id, the percentage does not show.It shows 0 but once I submit attendance again,the percentage shows. any idea?

Comment: @zak could be doesn't have record in daily_attendances.

Comment: this is going to be technical. in your case you will have to update it twice because the code is getting the percentage before it updates.

Comment: Is there any other method to solve the issue that will generate percentage when new attendance records being inserted?thanks

Comment: @zak I have updated the code. please do analyze it.